# is there any thing like the nested table of oracle DB in sql-server

Tags: sql-server, plsql, nested-table

I was working with PL/SQL, and really found the nested table very helpful, now i'm working with sql server and i need sth like the nested table in oracle DB. all what i found is a data mining related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the concept of nesting tables in columns does not exist in SQL server (up to 2012). You can define User-defined Table Types, but you can't use them to persists data into tables.

Comment: So far as I'm aware, Oracle's Nested Tables are a permanent part of the storage, and allow a table to be stored as a particular column's value, within another table. Nothing like CTEs.

Comment: Good point, thats something completely different. The CTEs are the way for recursion to query parent child relationships.